# RecyclerView only showing last item in JSON array

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

Based on the logs I added in, the request is receiving all the data correctly, and the issues lies somewhere in displaying the list in the recycler list. It just prints out the last item in the your server pets array and prints its according to the length of the database array. My leaderboard seems to only been showing the last entry into the database and repeating it for the pets array length. I would like to show the entire database items in each slot. Also, I am not sure why petPhoto is not being passed through like everything other thing.

```
***************************************ListAcitivty.kt:****************************************

package com.example.specialpets

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.android.volley.Request
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley
import org.json.JSONArray
import org.json.JSONObject

class ListActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list)
        var findArray: JSONArray
        val url = "https://jwuclasses.com/ugly/leaderboard"
        val jsonData=JSONObject();
        val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        val request = JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, jsonData,
            { response ->
                if (response.getInt("success") == 1) {
                    Log.e("app", "We have something good going on here");
                    findArray = response.getJSONArray("pets")
                    for (i in 0 until findArray.length()) {
                        val pet = findArray.getJSONObject(i)
                        val petListID = pet.getInt("id")
                        val petName = pet.getString("name")
                        val petBirthdate = pet.getString("birthdate")
                        val petRating = pet.getInt("rating")
                        val petVotes = pet.getDouble("votes")
                        val petPhoto = pet.getString("url")
                        jsonData.put("token",TokenBox.token)
                        
                        //pay no attention to the man behind the curtain
                        //val petName = response.getString("name")
                       // val petListID = response.getInt("id")
                        //val petRating = response.getInt("rating")
                       // val petBirthdate = response.getString("birthdate")
                       // val petVotes = response.getInt("votes")
                        val data = ArrayList<petViewModel>()
                        //data.sortDescending(); Why won't this work??? Maybe because it has to be in the declaration of the array
                        for(i in 0 until findArray.length()) {

                            data.add(
                                petViewModel(
                                    petListID,
                                    petName,
                                    petBirthdate,
                                    petRating,
                                    petVotes,
                                    petPhoto
                                )
                            )
                            val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerView)
                            recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
                            val adapter = petAdapter(data)
                            recyclerView.adapter = adapter
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e("app", "something isn't right here")
                }
            },{
                error ->
                Log.e("app", "Request did not go through and no JSON data was sent")

        })

        request.setShouldCache(false);
        queue.add(request);

        //val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerView)

        //val data = ArrayList<petViewModel>()
       // for(i in 1..20){}
        //****These are all my attempts at passing the data through a jsonObject request....
           // data.add(petViewModel("petListID", "petName", "petBirthdate", "petRating", "petVotes",)
            //take it from JSON, store it in a local array and store it
            //data.add(petViewModel("Item" + i, i))
           // data.add(petViewModel((response.getString("id"), response.getString("name"), response.getString("birthdate"), response.getString("rating"), response.getString("votes"))
            //data.add(petViewModel(2, 2, 3, 10))
           // data.add(petViewModel(response.getInt,"id", response.getString,"birthdate", response.getString""
            //data.add(petViewModel(reponse.getString,"name", response.getString,"birthdate", response.getString,"rating")
            //data.add(petViewModel("id",  "", "", "", ""))
            //data.add(petViewModel((response.getString"")))
            //data.add(petViewModel("id", "name", "rating", "birthdate", "votes"))

        //}

    }
}
```

```
******************************************PetViewModel:****************************************

package com.example.specialpets
//class designed to hold data
data class petViewModel(val id: Int, val name: String, val birthdate: String, val rating: Int, val votes: Double, val url: String){
    //id name birthdate rating votes url(picasso image)


}




******************************************PetAdapterModel:****************************************
package com.example.specialpets

import android.content.Intent
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.android.volley.Request
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso
import org.json.JSONArray
import org.json.JSONObject

//an array of petviewmodel instances
class petAdapter(val dataset: ArrayList<petViewModel>): RecyclerView.Adapter<petAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
//creates a new item or a new card for a pet
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.petcard, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }
//puts the position. specific information
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val petViewModel = dataset[position]
        holder.petListID.text = petViewModel.id.toString()
        holder.petName.text = petViewModel.name
        holder.petBirthdate.text = petViewModel.birthdate
        holder.petRating.text = petViewModel.rating.toString()
        holder.petVotes.text = petViewModel.votes.toString()
        //picassoimg
       holder.petListID.setOnClickListener{
            //grab id from data object which is inside the petviewmodel
            val zoomies = Intent(holder.petListID.context,ZoomerActivity::class.java)
            //store with the one click one
            zoomies.putExtra("ID", petViewModel.id.toString())
            zoomies.putExtra("name", petViewModel.name)
            zoomies.putExtra("birthdate", petViewModel.birthdate)
            zoomies.putExtra("rating", petViewModel.rating.toString())
            zoomies.putExtra("votes", petViewModel.votes.toString())
            zoomies.putExtra("url", petViewModel.url)
            //start the activity
            holder.petListID.context.startActivity(zoomies)
        }
    }
//tells me how many items are in the list
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return dataset.size
}

class ViewHolder(ItemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(ItemView){
    val petListID: TextView = ItemView.findViewById(R.id.petListID)
    val petName: TextView = ItemView.findViewById(R.id.petName)
    val petBirthdate: TextView = ItemView.findViewById(R.id.petBirthdate)
    val petRating: TextView = ItemView.findViewById(R.id.petRating)
    val petVotes: TextView = ItemView.findViewById(R.id.petVotes)
    }
}
```

I would like it to have every item instead of just the last item in the JSON array.I have tried changing the for loop to a forEach loop with no changes. I have tried altering the data class: dataset with no changes as well.
[this is what the app recyler view looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPLm6.png)

Comment: Probably you need to setup the RecyclerView after the second for loop

Comment: @Zain the recycler view is setup after the second for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following this:

```
   class YourAdapterName(
    private val context: Context,
    private val dataset: ArrayList<petViewModel>
    ) :
        RecyclerView.Adapter<HistoryAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    inner class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val yourview: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.historyInput)
        // and your other views 

        init {
            item.setOnClickListener {
            // here is what you want do when an item is clicked
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(viewGroup: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.yourRecyclerViewLayoutShouldBeHere, viewGroup, false)
        return ViewHolder(v)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val petViewModel = dataset[position]
        viewHolder.yourview.text = petViewModel.name
        // and your other views here
    }

    // Return the size of your ids
    override fun getItemCount() = dataset.size
  }
```

It should be all you need.